# How to set Formik FieldArray select options at various index values based on another selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am using a Formik FieldArray that consists of the following fields:

```
Pet Type
Pet Food
```

My `initialValues` setup for this FieldArray is as follows:

```
const myPetGroup = {
      petDetails: [
        {
          petSelection: [
            {
              petType: "",
              petFood: ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
};

const INITIAL_FORM_STATE = {
  allPets: [myPetGroup]
}
```

Based on the selection value for `Pet Type`, I need to assign a specific set of options to `Pet Food`. Obviously I need to make sure that values are maintained at each row index  level.

Assuming I have the following options for `Pet Type`

```
const petListOptions = [
  { value: "dog", label: "Dog" },
  { value: "cat", label: "Cat" }
];
```

The following are the two types of food options bases on pet selection:

```
const dogFood = [
  { value: "dog food choice a", label: "Dog Food A" },
  { value: "dog food choice b", label: "Dog Food B" }
]; 

const catFood = [
  { value: "cat food a", label: "Cat Food A" },
  { value: "cat food b", label: "Cat Food B" }
];
```

Assuming my FieldArray index is at 0:

```
<Select
  name={`petType.${index}`}
  options={petListOptions}
  value={dog}
/>
```

Based on `Pet Type` selection of `dog` how can I then set the following `select` to have the options of `dogFood` at index 0, that is:

```
<Select
  name={`petFood.${index}`}
  options={dogFood}
/>
```

Now if the user adds another row within the FieldArray, now at index 1 and now select `cat`, how can I set the options to now use `catFood` at index 1 ?

```
<Select
  name={`petType.${index}`}
  options={petListOptions}
  value={cat}
/>

<Select
  name={`petFood.${index}`}
  options={catFood}
/>
```

I am not sure how to set these Pet Food options at various indexes based on Pet List selection within my FieldArray.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the exact `initialValues` you are passing to Formik?

Comment: @MujeebQureshi - I have updated my question with `initialValues`. Hope you can assist.

Comment: Where does the <Select /> Component come from?

Comment: Have a look at this, and let me know if this is something you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-rftf82?file=/test.js
I'll post an explaination in the answer.

Comment: @MujeebQureshi - had a look and looks like what I am after. I am still going through your code but if you could please provide some explanation as part of your answer, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to understand correctly, you have to render a list of controls, one that makes selection of which type of pet and then based off of the first selection, the program renders the food options to choose from.

```
const petListOptions = [
  { value: "dog", label: "Dog" },
  { value: "cat", label: "Cat" }
];
```

The value selected from the first list would determine what options to render next. Therefore as an ease for retrival I have kept the key of the petFood array below to match the set set of possible values returned from first selection above.

```
const petFood = {
  dog: [
    { value: "dog food choice a", label: "Dog Food A" },
    { value: "dog food choice b", label: "Dog Food B" }
  ],
  cat: [
    { value: "cat food a", label: "Cat Food A" },
    { value: "cat food b", label: "Cat Food B" }
  ]
};
```

To save the values of petType and petFood we pass an array with the first object initialized where both petType and food properties are set to empty.
This will render out just one set of row(s).

In the code below : `<Field name={`petSelection.${index}.petType`} as="select" value={selectedPet.petType}> ... </Field>` tells formik of how to store the value of the selection.
Notice the `name` property on FieldArray. The property where you would want to store the value should then be `FieldArray's name <dot> Index`. If we want to place our value in a specific property, we can append `<dot> Property name` to the name of our Select Field.

```
export const PetsList = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Pet List</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        petSelection: [
          {
            petType: "",
            petFood: ""
          }
        ]
      }}
      onSubmit={(values) =>
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500)
      }
      render={({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <FieldArray
            name="petSelection"
            render={(arrayHelpers) => (
              <div>
                {values.petSelection && values.petSelection.length > 0 ? (
                  values.petSelection.map((selectedPet, index) => {
                    //console.log("selectedPet" + index, selectedPet);
                    return (
                      <div key={index}>
                        <Field
                          name={`petSelection.${index}.petType`}
                          as="select"
                          value={selectedPet.petType}
                        >
                          <option value="" disabled />
                          {petListOptions.map((pet, petIndex) => (
                            <option value={pet.value}>{pet.label}</option>
                          ))}
                        </Field>
                        {selectedPet.petType && (
                          <Field
                            name={`petSelection.${index}.petFood`}
                            as="select"
                            value={selectedPet.petFood}
                          >
                            <option value="" disabled />
                            {petFood[selectedPet.petType].map(
                              (food, foodIndex) => (
                                <option value={food.value}>{food.label}</option>
                              )
                            )}
                          </Field>
                        )}
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)} // remove a friend from the list
                        >
                          -
                        </button>
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          onClick={() =>
                            arrayHelpers.insert(index, {
                              petType: "",
                              petFood: ""
                            })
                          } // insert an new object at a position
                        >
                          +
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })
                ) : (
                  <button 
                      type="button" 
                      onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({
                          petType: "",
                          petFood: ""
                      })}>
                    {/* show this when user has removed all pets from the list */}
                    Add a Pet
                  </button>
                )}
                <div>
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  </div>
);
```

the add button just simply adds a new object to the `petsSelection` array with properties `petType` and `petFood` initialized to empty string.
Now at any row you make a selection, you are sure to add the values to this new object!

Comment: Great explanation and solved my issue. Thanks.